# Grounding new panel

Tags: grounding

My meter is two hots and a ground. Installing new breaker panel and new service wire from meter to panel. Current panel has neutral and ground connected. With the new 3 wire with neutral and ground best way to connect and ground new panel?

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: Are you using conduit between panels , and second is the new panel part of the existing structure or a detached structure it makes a difference and 4 conductors are needed if in the US. And possibly ground rods if detached.